# Can docker reuse a cached layer when ADDing a directory of files?

Tags: docker, pip

One of our docker builds is consistently not reusing a cache layer on CI. I've removed some non-relevant sections.

```
FROM python:2.7.11
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install "pip==9.0.3" "setuptools==39.2.0" && pip install "pipenv==2018.7.1"
ADD requirements/ /code/requirements/
RUN pip install -r requirements/docker.txt
ADD . /code
```

And the build output:

```
Step 5/9 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2b9b8888fcbd
Step 6/9 : RUN pip install "pip==9.0.3" "setuptools==39.2.0" && pip install "pipenv==2018.7.1"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e671bccc3d9
Step 7/9 : ADD requirements/ /code/requirements/
 ---> 7d6b63768850
Removing intermediate container 659522aa0ad1
Step 8/9 : RUN pip install -r requirements/docker.txt
 ---> Running in 6ff743d5e9b4
```

None of the files in `requirements/` have been changed, yet docker is choosing to rebuild that layer anyway. There are 5 files in that directory.

I'm suspecting that docker might ignore the cache if a directory is ADDed rather than a single file, but I can't find any information to prove or disprove that theory.

Edit:

Issuing 2 build commands one after the other *does* correctly use the cache. The issue is only on CI (Jenkins) where it clones the repo.

There are many PRs being built all day each day, from separate Jenkins slaves (using a shared docker host) that they may be trashing each others cache. That's a separate question and investigation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ADD` and  `COPY` commands do work with the build cache. Docker computes a hash on the directory contents that you are adding, and if the hash does not match the previous copy, it will not use the previous hash. This hash includes meta data on the files, including ownership and permissions. You can view the hash value with a `docker history` command after building your image to see if it changed.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I realised I could have tested this by issuing 2 build commands in a row to eliminate interference, and it does correctly use the cache. We're seeing this problem on our CI infrastructure, so I'm wondering if it could have something to do with the git checkout, or timestamp on a file?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton you can reduce the risk of external interference with a `.dockerignore` file, excluding things like the .git directory.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch - I ended up solving the issue. There was a zip file in the requirements directory which ADD explodes. Deleting that file and changing to COPY allows the cache to be used again. I also `RUN mkdir` the requirements directory before ADDing the txt files, but I'm unsure if that step was required.